# Improving performance on Image Mapster

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, imagemapster

I'm using Image Mapster to highlight the mapped areas from an image, the javascript file is generated by a php code and minified on the server side.

I'm having problems with the loading time, in the image on which I'm working I have near a thousand mapped areas and the load time of the javascript file takes about 10 seconds.

I want to know if someone have any suggestion to how can I reduce this load time.

I'm using the CodeIgniter 3 Framework, I'm sending the timeline from Google Chrome DevTools:

[image]